# PostgreSQL: UPDATE ... ON MISSING INSERT?

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, upsert

PostgreSQL has "`INSERT ... ON CONFLICT UPDATE`" construct, but in my queries in most cases I need UPDATE.

So I don't want that DB will try insert and only then update, I want that it will try `UPDATE` and if the record does not exist - will `INSERT`.

Is it possible?
Will it increase performance?

Comment: What do you expect to gain with that?

Comment: I expect performance increase, because I'll try first update, which is more likely to success in my situation

Comment: You could do `UPDATE` and if the row count is zero then `INSERT.. ON CONFLICT UPDATE`. Compare the methods with your actual data to check whether it's faster.

Comment: I need to do this in a single statement, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

It will increase performance, and it also depends which code you will have. If you construct a table and then use a separate function to check whether it has the data that you want to add or no, and then do accordingly(if exists- insert else no). In this case your code takes some part of memory. This method is good when working with a mass data, to save even a small part of memmory

Comment: Can I do it with single SQL statement, without functions?

Comment: Yes, sure. You can do this while inserting with where statement. Try this as an example:

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO hundred(name, name_slug, status) 
SELECT DISTINCT name, name_slug, status 
FROM hundred 
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( 
 SELECT 'X' 
 FROM temp_data 
 WHERE temp_data.name = hundred.name AND temp_data.name_slug = hundred.name_slug  AND temp_data.status = status );
```

To simplify, "where" statement is the key point to do what you want:

```
   INSERT INTO table (id, field, field2)
   SELECT 3, 'C', 'Z'
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE id=3);
```

Comment: Is that what you meant,  @Pavel Bernshtam

Comment: Sorry, I don't see where I do UPDATE in your example? I want first try UPDATE the table

Comment: UPDATE table (id, field, field2)
SET id= 3, field= 'C', field2='Z'
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE id=3);

Comment: i meant, u could use 'WHERE' stat-t to do the rest.

Comment: I see but how I do in a single statement "UPDATE if not succeeded then INSERT" ?